# convert html to github flavored markdown

Tags: html, github-flavored-markdown

Have anyone used this "remark. overzealous" library to convert from HTML to GitHub flavoured markdown. Actually, I am having problems to convert some HTML tag in GitHub markdown format like tag `<input>`. Also, I am not able to get GitHub task list from HTML code using this library.